# Easiest way to bring back a previous commit point to the top in Git

Tags: git, revert, git-revert

Ok, here is what I want, very like [Going back to certain previous commit and not modifying git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803706/):

Suppose my git log is like this:

```
detour C
detour B
detour A
Last good point
```

I want to revert to "Last good point", while still keeping the detours in the history, but unlike [Going back to certain previous commit and not modifying git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803706/), I want to make it top again. So afterward my git log would like:

```
Revert to last good point
detour C
detour B
detour A
Last good point
```

I know the official way is

`git revert HEAD~3`

However, I got

```
error: could not revert f755e55... Last good point
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
```

I.e., I need to resolve those very messy conflicts, which is what I want to avoid as much as possible. I know

```
git checkout HEAD~3
```

will bring me there right away, but I read then the git will be in a detached stage or something, and I don't know how to duplicate this stage back to the top again. Please help. Thx.

Comment: You should resolve the conflicts.  There is really no avoiding this.

Comment: It IS "_very messy_". `git checkout HEAD~3` will bring me there in no time, while resolving the conflicts will be painful & slow, and it might even introduce errors as well. Oh well, if as you said, there is really no avoiding this, then I'll revert to my file manipulating kungfu out side of `git` tool kit then. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revert multiple git commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/revert-multiple-git-commits)

Comment: @DavidZ, Ah, yeah, agree, but the accepted answer there is really _messy_ there. The second, clean solution, should clearly be the answer. Would you care to answer it here? I can accept it.

Comment: @xpt I don't think that would have been productive since several other answers had been posted by the time I saw this. Anyway it's good that you got your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

There are three fairly direct ways to achieve what you want:

1. `git revert --no-commit HEAD~3..HEAD && git commit`
2. `git read-tree --reset -u HEAD~3 && git commit`
3. `git rm -rf -- . && git checkout HEAD~3 -- . && git commit`

All three require that you enter the new commit message; you might add `-C HEAD~3 --edit` to the `git commit` command so that you can edit starting from the message that's in `HEAD~3`.  The last of these three require that you be in (`cd`-ed to) the top level of the repository.  If you are not already there, you should first use:

```
cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

or:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

and then cut and paste the output into a `cd` command to get to the top level.

#### Longer: why the above are correct, starting with #3

The key phrase is this:

> I want to revert ***to*** "Last good point"

(emphasis mine: *revert **to***, not just *revert*, which is a Git command that does something a bit different).

<s>You should also be wary of the word *stage*, too, which has a technical defined meaning in Git (referring to copying into the *staging area*, which is another phrase for the thing that Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *cache*, and of course the staging area).</s> [edit: removed since the title is adjusted now]

The low level command that does this is `git read-tree`, as in [PetSerAl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48088333/1256452).  I would recommend `git read-tree --reset -u`, since `-m` means to perform a *merge* and you want an index reset.  But there is a way to do this that, while slightly clumsier, may make more sense to humans, using `git checkout`.  That's command-set 3, which we will look at first.

As you note, `git checkout HEAD~3` will make the desired commit be the current commit—but it does so by "detaching HEAD", which is a scary phrase that just means that you are no longer on a named branch.  (You "re-attach" your HEAD by running `git checkout branchname`, which sets things up again so that you're on that branch, by checking out that branch's tip commit, which of course means you are no longer using the desired commit.)  This happens because *all* commits are more or less permanent,<sup>1</sup> and entirely read-only: you cannot *change* the past, you can only *re-visit* it.

The `git checkout` command, though, can do more than re-visit the past (by checking out a specific past commit) or switch to some other branch (by checking out any named branch).  Probably, many or most of these operations should have a different front-end command, because lumping them all under `git checkout` just makes Git more confusing; but that's what we have: `git checkout commit-specifier -- paths` tells `git checkout` to extract the given *`paths`* (file or directory names), into the index and then on into the work-tree, overwriting whatever is currently in the index and work-tree, *without* changing commits.

Hence:

```
git checkout HEAD~3 -- .
```

tells Git to extract, from commit `HEAD~3` (the one three steps back from where you are now), the directory `.`.  If you are in the top level of your Git repository, `.` names every file in the repository.

More precisely, `.` names every file in *that particular commit* of the repository.  This is why you should first run:

```
git rm -rf -- .
```

That tells Git to *remove* every file (that Git knows about, i.e., that's in the index right now) from both the index and work-tree.  The point of this is ... well, suppose that during the three detour commits, you added a *new* file `newfile.ext`.  That new file is in commit `detour C`, at least, if not in all three of those.  But it's *not* in `HEAD~3`, which names commit `22769c2`, the last good one that you want to restore.  So when you tell git `git checkout 22769c2 -- .` or equivalent, Git looks into `22769c2`, finds all the files *that commit* has—which doesn't include `newfile.txt`—and replaces the current files with the ones from the good commit, but *leaves `newfile.ext` in the index and work-tree.*

By first removing *everything* that Git knows about in the `detour C` commit, you give the `git checkout ... -- .` command a clean slate into which to extract everything.

Hence, command set 3 means:

- Remove everything that Git knows about, to produce a clean-slate index and work-tree.  (Files that Git *doesn't* know about, such as `.o` files built by a compiler, or `.pyc` byte-code files from Python, or whatever, that are ignored via a `.gitignore`, do not get removed.)
- Extract everything that was in the good commit, into the index and work-tree: fill the clean slate with the good stuff.
- Commit: make a *new* commit, not `22769c2` but some other hash ID, whose parent is the `detour C` commit but whose contents are whatever is in the index right now, which is the stuff we just extracted from `22769c2`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The "more or less" part is because you can *abandon* commits, by changing your various names so that no *name* locates those commits any more.  Having no names that find them, the commits become lost and abandoned.  Once they have been abandoned sufficiently long—generally at least 30 days as there are hidden *reflog entry* names that still find the commits, but those reflog entries eventually expire, typically in 30 days for such commits—Git's Grim <s>Reaper</s> Collector, also known as the *garbage collector* or `git gc`, will actually remove them.

---

#### The `git read-tree` method

What `git read-tree --reset` does is, to put it as simply as possible, combine the `git rm -r --cached .` step with most of the `git checkout HEAD~3 -- .` step.  Of course those aren't quite what are in #3 at all: this form, with `--cached`, removes only *index* entries.  Moreover, the `git checkout` step populates the work-tree.  That's what the `-u` addition to the command does: it updates the work-tree to match the changes made to the index.  Removing some entries, if any do wind up *removed*, causes the corresponding work-tree file to be removed; updating the rest of the entries, including adding new entries from the commit being read, causes the corresponding work-tree file to be updated or created.  So `git read-tree --reset -u HEAD~3` is the same as our remove-and-check-out sequence, except that it's more efficient.

(You might not remember it though: `git read-tree` is not a command one uses often.  Also, using `-m` tells Git to *merge* the target tree into the current index, which isn't quite what you want either, although it's almost certainly going to do the right thing here.)

#### Or you can use `git revert -n`

The first command above uses `git revert --no-commit`.  This is the long way to spell `-n`, which means *do each revert without committing the result.*  Normally, what `git revert` does is to turn each commit-to-be-reverted into a change-set, then "reverse apply" the changes.  Given a range of commits like `HEAD~3..HEAD`, Git first collects a list of all the hash IDs involved—in this case they are:

> ```
> 7a6c2cc detour C
> dc99368 detour B
> 1cf4eb4 detour A
> ```

Git then runs through them in backwards order, child-most to parent-most, i.e., first looking at `detour C`, then at `detour B`, then at `detour A`.

Each of these commits is a snapshot in itself, but each has a *parent* that is also a snapshot.  Subtracting what's in the `detour B` snapshot from what's in `detour C` tells Git, in effect, what *changed* in order to go from B to C.  Git can then "un-change" exactly those changes: if going from B to C added a line to `README.md`, *remove* that line from `README.md`.  If it removed a line from `a.txt`, *add* that line back to `a.txt`.  If it removed an entire file, put that file back; if it added a new file, remove it.

Once all of the changes have been backed-out (with the result matching what's in the detour B snapshot), `git revert`—which obviously should be called `git backout`—would normally make a new commit from the result; but with `-n`, it doesn't.  Instead, it leaves the result in the index and work-tree, ready to commit.  Then it moves on to the next commit in the list, which is that for detour B.  Git compares this to its parent to see what changed, and undoes those changes.  The result is, *in this case*, the same snapshot that's in detour A.

Had we started from something other than the detour C snapshot, though, backing out the detour C changes would have not matched detour B, and then backing out the detour B changes would not match what's in detour A.  But we did start from what's in the detour C snapshot.  So now Git backs out whatever changed in detour A, leaving—that's right!—whatever is in the last good commit.

This state is now in the index and work-tree, ready to commit.  So now we simply commit it as a new commit.  And that's command-sequence 1: revert (back out) the three bad ideas, in reverse order, which is guaranteed to work since we're starting with the snapshot in the last of them.  Don't commit any of the intermediate results.  Then, once the index and work-tree match the last good commit, make a new commit.

Comment: Much appreciated for the comprehensive explanation that can end the discussion once and for all. PS. I've changed the title to be "_point_" instead of "_stage_", please chip in if it need to be fixed further. Thanks!

Comment: Is not `--reset` also do *merge*? Because documentation says: *--reset*: **Same as -m**, except that unmerged entries are discarded instead of failing.

Comment: @PetSerAl: I think the documentation is wrong here, and that in particular, `git read-tree -m <treeish>` will leave an index entry for pathname *p* in place if `<treeish>` has no *p*. I should test this though.

Comment: `git read-tree -m <treeish>` will leave an index entry for pathname p in place if `<treeish>` has no p. That is not true. Except for stat info resulting index for `git read-tree -m <treeish>` and `git read-tree <treeish>` will be the same.

Comment: Hm, OK, then `-m` should be fine too. I've always used it with `--reset` for this type of operation myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply read tree from `Last good point` commit, and then commit it:

```
git read-tree -m -u HEAD~3
git commit
```

`-m -u` options of `read-tree` will update working directory from given tree.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to `git revert` which would leave you with the same information, yet would avoid messy merge conflicts.  Just checkout a new branch from your current point and then hard reset that branch to the earlier point:

```
git checkout your_branch
git checkout -b new_branch
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Now `new_branch` is functionally what you want, plus you still have those three commits sitting in the bona fide `your_branch` branch.

Comment: So after the above maneuver, the `Last good point` will be at the top of the `new_branch`. Hmm..., so is it possible to keep the commit history in a `my_detours` branch, while reset the `master` branch instead? -- Just want to keep as few branches as possible. thx.

Comment: @xpt No.  If you want those 3 commits in the history, but for their effect to be cancelled out, then revert is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert your commits one by one in the reverse order to avoid fixing merge conflicts and finally reach the required commit.

Suppose you have the following history initially.

```
7a6c2cc detour C
dc99368 detour B
1cf4eb4 detour A
22769c2 Last good point
```

You can run the following sequence of `git revert` commands.

```
git revert 7a6c2cc
git revert dc99368
git revert 1cf4eb4
```

This will leave you with a commit history like below.

```
3b67aaf Revert "detour A"
9028879 Revert "detour B"
6d9bcce Revert "detour C"
7a6c2cc detour C
dc99368 detour B
1cf4eb4 detour A
22769c2 Last good point
```

At the end, your code will the same as it was at the `Last good point` commit.

You can also use the `--no-commit` flag with `git revert` to avoid individual commits for each revert.

```
git revert --no-commit 7a6c2cc
git revert --no-commit dc99368
git revert --no-commit 1cf4eb4
git commit -m "Revert detour C, B and A"
```