# Revert git to a specific commit after many bad merges

Tags: git

Ok, I'm fairly familiar with git, including git revert and git reset.  I think that what I want to do can't be done, but just wanted to double-check.

Let's assume I have a repo into which a colleague has made dozens of bad merge commits.  I want to reset the repo back to the last known good commit.  I don't want to use a reset and have to do a force push, because that will mess up the local copy of all my other colleagues.  I also don't think revert can very easily be used to undo dozens of merge commits.

My best idea is to clone a second copy of the repo, checkout the right commit, and then go to my original local copy, make a branch, delete every file, and copy everything from the second repo.  Then commit, push, merge normally.  Can I improve on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I revert multiple Git commits (already pushed) to a published repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780228/how-can-i-revert-multiple-git-commits-already-pushed-to-a-published-repository)

Comment: @Mureinik Does that play nicely with merge commits? That particular issue wasn’t addressed there.

Comment: @DanielH it **should**, but I admit I haven't tried. Why don't you give it a try and tell us how it went?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could combine all this into operations on one git repo.

```
git checkout <branch in question>
rm -Rf * # This will leave the .git directory and any other hidden files in the root that you may need to manually further deal with
git checkout <good sha> -- .
git add .
# commit, test, etc. as required
```

Comment: That will also leave the .gitignore, and remove ignored files you might want to keep.

Comment: I can live with that

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for your commit hash `<commit>`:

```
git revert --no-commit <commit>..HEAD
git commit -m "Reverted a bunch of bad merges"
```

Comment: Thanks - this will follow merged branches okay?  Usually you have to use the -m for reverting branches so it know which path to take

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-liner option, if you don't mind running a plumbing command.  With `master` (or whatever branch is going to receive the new "revert" commit) checked out:

```
 git reset --hard `git commit-tree -p HEAD -m "revert to last good state" <good-commit>^{tree}`
```

where `<good-commit>` is the ID (or some other valid name - maybe a tag, or an expression like `HEAD~15`) for the commit whose state you want.

This does use `reset`, but it does it in a way that honors the "normal" direction of branch movement, so no force-push and no clean-up of other repos will be needed.

Comment: Thanks - not totally clear what that's doing but I'll try it out and read about commit-tree...

Comment: You can also use `git read-tree --reset -u <hash>; git commit`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48090390/1256452